# Tensorflow can't feed (run session) when dropout layer exist

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm tring to make an image classifier using tensorflow (with tensorlayer) and I met several problems.
One of them is that I can't get tensor's value for debug usage with dropout layers in my network.

The network looks like this:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 100, 100, 3], name='x')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, ], name='y_')

w_init = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)
b_init = tf.constant_initializer(value=0.0)
inputs = tl.layers.InputLayer(x, name='inputs')
conv1 = tl.layers.Conv2d(inputs, 64, (5, 5), act=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME', W_init=w_init, b_init=b_init, name='conv1')
    #(?, 96, 96, 64)
pool1 = tl.layers.MaxPool2d(conv1, (2, 2), padding='SAME', name='pool1')
    #(?, 48, 48, 64)
conv2 = tl.layers.Conv2d(pool1, 128, (5, 5), act=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME', W_init=w_init, b_init=b_init, name='conv2')
    #(?, 44, 44, 64)
pool2 = tl.layers.MaxPool2d(conv2, (2, 2), padding='SAME', name='pool2')
    #(?, 22, 22, 128)
conv3 = tl.layers.Conv2d(pool2, 256, (5, 5), act=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME', W_init=w_init, b_init=b_init, name='conv3')
    #(?, 18, 18, 256)
pool3 = tl.layers.MaxPool2d(conv3, (2, 2), padding='SAME', name='pool3')
    #(?, 9, 9, 256)
flatten = tl.layers.FlattenLayer(pool3, name='flatten_layer')
    #(?, 20736)
drop1 = tl.layers.DropoutLayer(flatten, keep=0.8, name='drop1')
    #(?, 20736)
relu2 = tl.layers.DenseLayer(drop1, n_units=512, act = tf.nn.relu, name='relu2')
    #(?, 512)
drop3 = tl.layers.DropoutLayer(relu2, keep=0.5, name='drop3')
    #(?, 512)
network = tl.layers.DenseLayer(drop3, n_units=1, act = tf.identity, name='output_layer')
    #(?, 2)

y = network.outputs
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(y, 1), y_)
```

And I want to find what `correct_prediction` is, so I run the session with inputs feeded into the network.

```
print(sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={
    x: np.asarray(X_train[0:10],dtype=np.float32), 
    y_: np.asarray(Y_train[0:10],dtype=np.float32), 
    drop1:0.8, 
    drop3:0.5
}))
```

But after that I got the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
```

By tracing into stack, I found that it's the dropout layer that caused the problem:

```
......
Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "run_linear_output.py", line 33, in <module>
    drop1 = tl.layers.DropoutLayer(flatten, keep=0.8, name='drop1')
  File "/home/neoclub/wanghong/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorlayer/layers.py", line 963, in __init__
    set_keep[name] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  File "/home/neoclub/wanghong/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
    name=name)
......
```

After remove those layers from my network, I can get the result successfully.

```
......
[False False False False False False False False False False]
......
```

Obviously it's wrong (edit: because I forgot to round the output here), but that's other problem.

After that, I noticed that in the error message there is `set_keep[name] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)`, so I changed my feed like this

```
print(sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={
    x: np.asarray(X_train[0:10],dtype=np.float32), 
    y_: np.asarray(Y_train[0:10],dtype=np.float32), 
    drop1:0.8, 
    drop3:0.5
}))
```

But I got another error :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_linear_output.py", line 79, in <module>
    print(sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={x: np.asarray(X_train[0:10],dtype=np.float32), y_: np.asarray(Y_train[0:10],dtype=np.float32), drop1:0.8, drop3:0.5}))
  File "/home/neoclub/wanghong/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/neoclub/wanghong/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 933, in _run
    + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a DropoutLayer into a Tensor.
```

I'm totally confused here. How do I use dropout layer properly? What should I feed to make the session runnable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeds are used to place data into your graph, often through placeholders.
In your feed dict you are trying to feed drop1 the value 0.8 but drop1 = your dropout layer. I think what you want to do is create two placeholders that will be your dropout rates.

Something like:

```
drop_keep_1=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,None,name='drop_keep_1')
drop1=tl.layers.DropoutLayer(flatten, keep=drop_keep_1, name='drop1')
```

I notice you aren't using the Tensorflow Layers API but instead tl.layers (which i've never heard of) but I imagine that the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

you have **TWO** ways to use **DropoutLayer** in TensorLayer:

1) Use the internal keep prob placeholder created by TensorLayer, see [tutorial_mlp_dropout1.py](https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/blob/master/example/tutorial_mlp_dropout1.py)

2) Instead of using placeholder to control the keep prob, we build two graphs for training and testing, see [tutorial_mlp_dropout2.py](https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/blob/master/example/tutorial_mlp_dropout2.py)

Answer (score -1):

```
network = tl.layers.DropoutLayer(network, keep = 0.5, is_fix = True, name = 'drop1')
```

add `is_fix = True` is the point